# How to call node function in angular application

Tags: node.js, angular

I have this working code in node project

```
export function startWhatsapp(){
const qrcode = require('qrcode-terminal');

const { Client } = require('whatsapp-web.js');
const client = new Client();

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true});
});

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
});

client.initialize();
}
```

I need to use it in my angular app
what is the best practice to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `node` web server, setup with `express`. It is quite easy to setup, then expose a simple API from the express server and use `HttpClient` from Angular to call the API.

https://expressjs.com/

If you want it more real time, based on the event, you can even use `socket.io` with node express server.

https://medium.com/@raj_36650/integrate-socket-io-with-node-js-express-2292ca13d891

You can use socket.io even on client side, so the it allow real time communication.